# Rational behind separating nginx and PHP-FPM in two docker containers

Tags: nginx, docker, php-fpm

I see here and there that separating Nginx and PHP-FPM in two Docker containers is a common approach.

In my environment (basic 'not so big' Symfony application) i setup both inside the same container using unix socket for communication.

What are the benefits to separate them in two distincts containers ?

At first glance i'm thinking of finer scaling granularity, separation of concerns.. but on the other hand i see some extra performance cost due to network involved communication (tcp stack) between the two container even if this may be negligible if containers are hosted on the same host.

Any advice appreciated.